# Uncheck a checkbox in IE

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, checkbox

I am trying to uncheck an already checked checkbox on a webpage using excel VBA.

HTML code:

```
<div class="mycheckbox checked">
<label class="mycheckbox1 checked" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input name=<name> class=<class> id=<id> type="checkbox" checked="checked"></input></label></div>
```

VBA code stub:

```
    Public Sub uncheck(IE As Object)
    Dim Element As Object
        With IE.Document
            Set Element = .getElementById(<id>)
            Element.Checked = False
            Element.defaultChecked = False        
        End With
    End Sub
```

This does not work out as desired as HTML code changes to -

```
<div class="mycheckbox checked">
<label class="mycheckbox1 checked" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input name=<name> class=<class> id=<id> type="checkbox" checked=""></input></label></div>
```

The checkbox is not unchecked as there is still the checked attribute

Even tried the below(Clicking on the checkbox). It does not do anything at all -

```
    Public Sub uncheck(IE As Object)
    Dim Element As Object
        With IE.Document
            Set Element = .getElementById(<id>)
            Element.Click
        End With
    End Sub
```

Any suggestions? Or may I know why my approach not working?

Comment: Does checkbox is a part of form?

Comment: Hey!! I'm editing the question as I found [this](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#checkbox-usage-data-attributes). I guess I adding a little more html might help figure out.

Comment: Why not to replace `<name>`, `<class>` and `<id>` with certain string values? That would improve readability, it's confusing since actually is wrong syntax.

Comment: @omegastripes I get it but why go for random strings. Its better to go for placeholder. **I am unable to put the real ones due to some privacy policy**. Anyways you can very well consider them id1, class1, name1 to suit yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code that allows to make a common test if we can uncheck the checkbox:

```
Public Sub TestIE()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Element As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "about:blank"
    IE.document.write "<html><body><input name=""chkbx_name"" class=""chkbx_cls"" id=""chkbx"" type=""checkbox"" checked=""checked""></body></html>"
    IE.document.parentWindow.alert "Verify checkbox is checked"
    Set Element = IE.document.getElementById("chkbx")
    Element.Checked = False
    IE.document.parentWindow.alert "Verify checkbox is unchecked"
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

For me it works as expected: shows checked checkbox and first alert, then unchecks it and shows second alert. If your webpage is working in other way then it pays to inspect the checkbox on your webpage for some `onclick` or `onchange` event handler via developer tools. In IE, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, click *DOM Explorer*, select the checkbox in HTML code, click *Events* tab. If there is any event handler then you have to clarify if it modifies the state of the checkbox or not (immediately after your VBA does).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes it has events for both label and input elements. I'll have to study them then. I'll comeback and vote this as required answer if those events would be the real culprits